# How to send a custom header with cookies

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http, cookies

I have a scenario where I need to send a customer header but also want the browser to send all cookies. I am making an AJAX call such as -

```
var xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttpReq.open("GET", uri, false);
xmlHttpReq.withCredentials = true;
var  headers = {'id': "someId"}
function setHeaders(headers){
  for(let key in headers) {
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader(key, header4[key]) 
  }
}
setHeaders(headers);
xmlHttp.send("");
```

The browser is not sending any cookies. If I don't send any customer header, the cookies are going fine. Is this the limitation of AJAX?

This code is running in a subdomain of the parent domain in an iframe. The domain from which the call is made is something like api.xyz.com and the call is also made to api.xyz.com and the parent domain cookies are set to .xyz.com